# Element of a Multidimensional Array, Java

Tags: java

I have an array:

```
public String[][] bombBoard = new String[9][9];
```

This array is filled with values (*), however randomly throughout there are some other values (@).

Later in the program I want to tell the user how where the (@) is, if there are in the vicinity:

```
public void loadNumbers()
{
    try
    {
        if (bombBoard[bombRow][bombCol] == "@") 
        {
            System.out.println("You have landed on a bomb!");
            //break
        }
        else if (bombBoard[bombRow+1][bombCol].equals("@"))
        {
            System.out.println("There is a bomb in the vicinity!" + bombBoard[bombRow+1][bombCol]);
        }
        else if (bombBoard[bombRow-1][bombCol] == "@")
        {
            System.out.println("There is a bomb in the vicinity!" + bombBoard[bombRow-1][bombCol]);
        }
        else if (bombBoard[bombRow][bombCol+1] == "@")
        {
            System.out.println("There is a bomb in the vicinity!" + bombBoard[bombRow][bombCol+1]);
        }
        MORE CODE...
    }

}
```

It prints: `"There is a bomb in the vicinity!@"`

I want it to print `"There is a bomb at 3, 2"`

Probably so simple, but I'm drawing blanks. Instead of pulling back whats inside the element, I want the element index (I presume). Please halp!

Comment: Compare `String` values with `String`'s `equals` method, not with the `==` operator.  You did it correctly on the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just want to print out the coordinates of the `@`? If so you can do it like this:

```
System.out.println("There is a bomb at " + bombRow + ", " + bombCol + 1);
```

Use the same pattern for the other conditions. Also, you want to compare strings using `.equals` instead of `==` (the latter only compares references).

Comment: This worked with a slight modification (instead of bombCol + 1, I used (bombCol + 1)) since it wasn't doing Math without the parens! Thanks.

Comment: I changed them all to == and it seems to work. How does .equals differ from == besides the obvious?

Comment: @RichardS I assume it works because of string interning. `.equals` will compare the actual String's contents whereas `==` only checks to see if they point to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 System.out.println("There is a bomb in the vicinity!" + (bombRow+1).toString() +"," +bombCol.toString());
```